# WinError 10061 : NLTK - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, server, client, nltk, windows-firewall

I want to download **stopwords** and **punkt** using the syntax:

```
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')
```

But it always throws me an error

[image]

I have tested all possible method but the problem persist.